# Asp.net Intranet Application in local Networks with out IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking

I developed an asp.net (2.0) intranet Application  for local network in an organisation..
so we have 10 systems every one should access that site by ://192.xxx.x.xx/xyz(website name) ...
so now their requirement is not to type total ip adress.they need just by typing ://xyz they have to  browse the intranet application..how to solve this issue..?
Thanks 
Veduru

Answer (score 2):

Go to every one of this 10 computers, and in this directory

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\
```

find the **host** file and add the conversion of ip to name as

```
192.168.1.10  xyz
```

etc

and then you can access the site as `http://xyz`

Comment: +1. And if you have control over the DNS or WINS server, you can just add an entry for xyz in a central location (and assuming that .mydomain.com is the default DNS suffix)

Comment: @nonnb Yes of course, but if the user knows more complex thinks like DNS Server or WINS is never going to ask that :) so a simple fast solution that works

Comment: @Aristos -- that's exactly why he needs to learn.  Manually editing each hosts file is probably the last thing I'd do.  Local DNS modification is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your network admin about setting up a DNS entry for your application in the local DNS server.  If you have multiple web sites running on your web server, look into configuring IIS host headers to ensure the users get directed to the proper web application.

Please do not manually edit the `hosts` file on each machine unless it is absolutely, positively necessary, and only do so as a last resort.  When your 10-machine application expands to 100, or if your server IP ever changes, you will thank me later :)

Comment: If the 10 machines expands to 100, then their are relocate to find a bigger room and then they hire for sure an IT person that knows how to solve that :). I also think that the solution "talk to the right person to solve it" is not actually give solution. If you wish to get +1 from me give here all the steps to setup a dns server and the really solution (or links that do that) and how to setup clients to get the dns from the dns server first, then from the internet.

Comment: @Aristos -- first, we don't know if he already has a "bigger room" and if he already has an IT person that handles this.  Second, "talk to the right person" is indeed the right answer, depending on his organization -- should he go about modifying the local DNS server without the admin knowing about it?  Third, we don't know what kind of network setup he has, so I can't give a step-by-step guide on setting up DNS...that's beyond the scope of stackoverflow.  If anything, he can ask on server fault, as that is a network issue and not a programming issue.  Or just google 'how to set up DNS'.